# gpt operation not permitted in Ventura

Tags: command-line, partition, ventura

Trying to run the gpt command with anything other than show returns an 'operation not permitted' error, regardless of using sudo, running in a root shell, making sure disk is unmounted, and even disabling SIP. The command was working fine for me in Monterey; it is only after the Ventura upgrade that I am noticing issues. Anyone else facing this and has a potential solution?

Examples (with disk4 being the flash drive I'm trying to partition):

sudo gpt remove -a /dev/disk4

`gpt remove: operation not permitted: remove`

In fact, running gpt show with no arguments prints out the expected `usage: gpt show [-l] device ...`, but anything else comes back with the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third party [GPT fdisk](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) (`gdisk`) command can be used as a substitute for the `gpt` command. The command can be downloaded from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).

Like `fdisk`, the `gdisk` command is interactive. This means the `gdisk` command reads a both the Mast Boot Record (MBR) table and the GUID Partition Table (GPT) into memory. You can then interactively issue commands to make changes to the copies in memory, then write the changes out when finished. The `gpt` command writes out changes after executing each command.

Comment: This tool is SO much better than gpt, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not the only one experiencing this after upgrading to Ventura. I saw some users suggesting using the diskutil command instead of gpt as a workaround​, check this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/13p3s06/gpt_command_in_ventura/)

If you want to delete a partition, you can use the: "diskutil eraseVolume" command followed by the partition type, partition name, and the path. Here is an example:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ eDrive /dev/disk0s4
```

In this example, HFS+ is the partition type, eDrive is the partition name, and /dev/disk0s4 is the path. You will need to replace these with your specific values

Comment: That was actually me who posted that, lol